# How can I dynamically create unique objects within .each()?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm running a .each() on a list of items and categorizing those items in my HTML. In a function after that I'm checking which of those items is checked (checkboxes). In my function (prepareTrainings();) that finds which boxes were checked, I need it to display data from the result of the .each(). Basically, if the user checked X checkbox, show the Course Name and URL for that item...

My question: I'm not sure what would be best practice. Should I be creating an object to store those values inside my if(trainingGroup etc.) statements?

```
$.ajax({
url: "mySite",
type: "GET",
headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
success: function(data){
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index) { 
    var $this = $(this);
    var courseName = $this.attr('Title'); 
    var courseNumber = $this.attr('Course_x0020_Number'); 
    var courseUrl = $this.attr('URL'); 
    var trainingGroup = $this.attr('Training_x0020_Group'); 
    var recurrence = $this.attr('Recurrence'); 

    var dynCourseId = courseName.replace(/\s+/g, '')

        if (trainingGroup == 'Group1') {
            if (recurrence == "Don't Specify") {recurrence = '';
            } else recurrence = " ("+recurrence+")"; 
            document.getElementById('officeListSpan').innerHTML += '<ul class="courseLists"><li><input type="checkbox" id="'+dynCourseId+'"/>'+courseName+recurrence+'</li></ul>';
        }
        if (trainingGroup == 'Group2') {
            if (recurrence == "Don't Specify") {recurrence = '';
            } else recurrence = " ("+recurrence+")"; 
            document.getElementById('labListSpan').innerHTML += '<ul class="courseLists"><li><input type="checkbox" id="'+dynCourseId+'"/>'+courseName+recurrence+'</li></ul>';
        }
    });
    },
    error:  function(){
    alert("Failed to query SharePoint list data. Please refresh (F5).");
    }
});
function prepareTrainings() {
var idSelector = function() { 
    return this.id; 
};
var checkedCourses = $(":checkbox:checked").map(idSelector).get();
    alert("IDs for Courses Selected: " + checkedCourses);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping your processed objects in a global `var` makes sense. Define e.g. an object like so:

```
var courses = {};
```

Then in your `.each` function, extract the information from your HTML elements like you already do and store each result in another object:

```
$.each(data.d.results, function(index) { 
    var $this = $(this);
    var course = {}; //Create empty object


    course.name = $this.attr('Title'); 
    course.number = $this.attr('Course_x0020_Number'); 
    course.url = $this.attr('URL'); 
    course.trainingGroup = $this.attr('Training_x0020_Group'); 
    course.recurrence = $this.attr('Recurrence'); 
    course.id = course.name.replace(/\s+/g, '')

    //Store your course by id in the courses object
    courses[course.id] = course;

    //...
```

Later when checking which checkboxes are checked, you can retrieve the information of each course like so:

```
var checkedIDs = $(":checkbox:checked").map(idSelector).get();
var course = courses[checkedIDs[0]]; //fetches the first selected course

//Now you can do whatever with the data, like print lists...
(...).innerHTML += '<ul class="courseLists"><li><input type="checkbox" id="'+course.id+'"/>'+course.name+course.recurrence+'</li></ul>';
```

I hope I understood your question correctly, if not leave a comment.

Comment: It worked! I must not have read your response very clearly this morning. But this does work. Thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem :) You should mark this as the correct answer for others.

Comment: I'm still new to that part of stackoverflow. How can I mark it? I was looking for a way to "upvote" you, etc. Thanks again, you really helped!

Comment: There should be a check mark next to the answer which you can click so that it is green. "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers